# Cube Scramble Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, web

I need a Rubiks cube generator for my project. I searched a lot but I only found websites that provide me a scramble but do not provided a method/function to do so. Is there a way for me to make my own or is an algorithm already available. Thanks

Comment: If you were given a physical Rubik's Cube, would you have to search websites for instructions on how to scramble it? If not, then don't you already have one solution to your problem?

Comment: take a look at this: [Quaternion rotation do not works as excepted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39024016/2521214) you will find there C++ code for my rubi cube slice rotations so just first init your cube to solved state and then randomly turn random slices ...

Comment: @PaulHankin so I just make an array like [R, L, R', L', F, F'] etc and just pick a random rotation from it? I thought about it but it just didnt seem right.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find yourself a way how to represent the cube (each side and each cell of a side)
2. Determine, how your representation changes when rotating a horizontal section once clockwise and how your representation changes when rotating a vertical section once clockwise.
3. n times, randomly select a horizontal or vertical section and rotate it once clockwise.