# prolog - BFS algorithm to solve rubik cube issue

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, prolog, breadth-first-search

I'm wondering how to run BFS algorithm for rubik cube that is an input parameter of my function. So far I have created functions `rotateUp(cubeIn, cubeOut), rotateDown(cubeIn, cubeOut2), rotateFront(cubeIn, cubeOut), rotateBack(cubeIn, cubeOut), rotateLeft(cubeIn, cubeOut), rotateRight(cubeIn, cubeOut)` to rotate every single side of rubik cube.

Now I'm about to run some recursive function, where I can rotate my cube every possible way and then chceck if rubik cube is solved.

I already tried this solution but its going only deeper and deeper:

```
bfs(cubeIn) :-
        rotateUp(cubeIn, cubeOut1), bfs(cubeOut1),
        rotateDown(cubeIn, cubeOut2), bfs(cubeOut2),
        rotateFront(cubeIn, cubeOut3), bfs(cubeOut3),
        rotateBack(cubeIn, cubeOut4), bfs(cubeOut4),
        rotateLeft(cubeIn, cubeOut5), bfs(cubeOut5),
        rotateRight(cubeIn, cubeOut6), bfs(cubeOut6).
```

So I wanted to implement BFS algorithm for my rubik cube issue and I made this one:

```
bfs(cubeIn) :-
        rotateUp(cubeIn, cubeOut1),
        rotateDown(cubeIn, cubeOut2),
        rotateFront(cubeIn, cubeOut3),
        rotateBack(cubeIn, cubeOut4),
        rotateLeft(cubeIn, cubeOut5),
        rotateRight(cubeIn, cubeOut6),
        bfs(cubeOut1),bfs(cubeOut2),bfs(cubeOut3),
        bfs(cubeOut4),bfs(cubeOut5),bfs(cubeOut6).
```

But in the end it is still not working like BFS.
Don't you have any idea what I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: ?? variables **must** start uppercase

Comment: @CapelliC let's say it is a pseudocode, I have more operations inside bfs(), I just wanted to show what I'm about to create..

Comment: So, how do you pass the state around ? of course, you could do with some hack - binding **constants** like cubeOut1 to actual data structures, but seems completely useless... maybe you should show something like `bfs(CubeIn) :-
        rotateUp(CubeIn, CubeOut1),
        rotateDown(CubeOut1, CubeOut2), ...`

Comment: First only define **one** transition, then use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868)

Comment: I am not using BFS for solver but still this: [Quaternion rotation do not works as excepted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39024016/2521214) might get you some ideas

Answer (score 1):

For BFS you need to expand all the nodes for one level, then expand the nodes for next level. But the pseudocode expands one node, then goes to next level by calling bfs() iteratively. It is not BFS, but more like DFS.

BFS itself is not enough to solve Rubik's cube. You have 6 faces and each face can turn 90 degree, 180 degree or 270 degree. So you will have 3*6=18 possible turns. Having such a big branching factor, you will soon run out of memory for BFS. One possible solution is to break it down into several stages, then each stage could be solved using IDDFS. Thistlethwaite's algorithm is a good starting point for any one interested in solving Rubik's cube.