# Pseudorandom algorithm for color shifting rubik's cube?

Tags: algorithm, rubiks-cube

I was thinking of ways to programmatically create one of the evil-est rubik's cubes. Then I thought of a concept I had seen on youtube known as a color shifting rubik's cube, which was also [available on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VXR4GMG) apparently.
The concept was that the color of the cube changes depending on what angle you would look at. However, to make things a bit more challenging, I wanted to create a cube that would literally shift colors permanently on each rotation.

Here's what I came up with:

1. Starts off with a simple, solved cube
2. Scrambles the cube in random
3. Here's the fun part: With each rotation, the color of a few cells being shifted change position e.g. if one rotation line has the colors r-g-b on one face, they shift to b-r-g
4. The algorithm works in a way that the color shift is pseudorandom, not random, so the cube is still solvable
5. color shifts on multiple faces along the rotation line may take place as long as it does not render the cube unsolvable.

However,I'm having major problems understanding how I would be able to create an algorithm that does psuedorandom color shifts without rendering the cube unsolvable. For random shifts I could simply add the rotation line in a buffer and then use some shuffling algorithm [like fisher yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) but keeping track of each cell and creating a solvable shift accordingly is what I can't get my head around.

Is creating an algo for this even possible? Or is it just a crap idea?

Comment: Work on creating a standard Rubik's cube application.  Your application logical model would be the basis for your color-shift Rubik's cube application.  You have to be able to calculate that the cube is solvable to color-shift properly.

Comment: 1. see [Quaternion rotation does not work as excepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024016/2521214) for some ideas (and try the demo so you got feeling of the user interface) 2. I would use this [well known gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214) where each face color used will be represented by a wavelength. And the shifting will just increment the wavelengths slightly wrapping around visible spectra range. You can based the shift on angle between face original orientation vs camera view direction (simple dot product)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Makes sense. The way I create the logic for the Rubix is going to be the base for how I add the color-shifting property

Comment: @Spektre Thankyou for the link, that's a really comprehensive resource. Though the color shift I'm trying to achieve is not on the basis of camera viewing angle, but rather the rotations that permanently swap colors no matter what the viewing angle may be

Comment: @Meh mine representation of the Rubik cube is holding transform matrix for each subcube so the axises of each sub cube can be used for this ...  So I was thinking of using that (not the camera matrix) ...

Comment: Oh ok understood