# 2x2 Rubiks Cube Operation Program in C

Tags: c, algorithm, rubiks-cube

I recently tried to code a simple program, which can do the 6 basic operations, such as "Turn the Top", "Turn the Bottom", "Turn the Left Side", of a 2x2 Rubik's Cube. (All of these operations are meant to be 90° clockwise!

I began to try to create a function which can rotate the top of the 2x2 Rubik's cube by 90°. In theory I thought the code should work, but when I tried to print out the Basic Rubik's cube I got many issues with GCC such as "Stack Smashing". I really don't know where my mistake is, I thought the hardest part was the thinking process (To understand how the cube works, and which parts of the array are moving) but no I came across problems with the coding/compiling.

If I fix this problem, the implementation of the other 5 operation functions won't be that hard, because I follow a simple thought (Which is explained in the ASCII-Drawn-Comment).

I would be very thankful if anyone can help me by locating and fixing my problem. Thank you :)

In the following there is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char rubik_t[6][2][2];

/*
Rotation in General:

           top1 top2                                                            left1 left2
                                             90° Turn                   
left2   sideTopL sideTopR   right1      -------------------->          bottom2   sideBotL sideTopL      top1    
left1   sideBotL sideBotR   right2      -------------------->          bottom1   sideBotR sideTopR      top2     

         bottom2 bottom1                                                        right2 right1


*/

//Copy the Input Cube into a new Array
char *copyRubik(rubik_t rubik, rubik_t *copied){
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            for(k = 0; k < 2; k++){
                *copied[i][j][k] = rubik[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//Function to turn the Top of the Cube
void turnTop(rubik_t *copied){
    char temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5;
    char *left1 = copied[0][0][1];
    char *left2 = copied[0][1][1];
    char *right1 = copied[2][1][1];
    char *right2 = copied[2][0][1];
    char *top1 = copied[3][0][1];
    char *top2 = copied[3][1][1];
    char *bottom1 = copied[1][1][1];
    char *bottom2 = copied[1][0][1];
    char *sideTopL = copied[4][0][1];
    char *sideBotL = copied[4][0][0];
    char *sideTopR = copied[4][1][1];
    char *sideBotR = copied[4][1][0];

    temp1 = *top1;
    temp2 = *top2;
    temp3 = *sideBotL;
    temp4 = *sideTopL;
    temp5 = *sideTopR;
    *left1 = *bottom1;
    *left2 = *bottom2;
    *sideBotL = *sideBotR;
    *right1 = temp1;
    *right2 = temp2;
    *sideTopL = temp3;
    *sideTopR = temp4;
    *sideBotR = temp5;
    *top1 = *left1;
    *top2 = *left2;
    *bottom1 = *right1;
    *bottom2 = *right2;
}

int main(){

//Basic (solved) Rubik's cube
rubik_t cube_ordered = {
  {{'B','B'},{'B','B'}},       
  {{'O','O'},{'O','O'}},       
  {{'G','G'},{'G','G'}},       
  {{'R','R'},{'R','R'}},       
  {{'W','W'},{'W','W'}},       
  {{'Y','Y'},{'Y','Y'}}   
};
     rubik_t copiedCube;
     char *copied = malloc(25);
     copyRubik(cube_ordered, &copiedCube);
     turnTop(&copiedCube);
     
//  Print the Cube  
     int i, j, k;
     for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            for(k = 0; k < 2; k++){
                printf("%c", copiedCube[i][j][k]);
                if(k == 1){
                    printf(" ");
                    if(j == 1){
                        printf("\n");
                        if(i == 5){
                            printf("\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
     
     free(copied);
     return 0;
}
```

I had a whole thinking process in how to solve the problem, tried to implement it into Code, but came across many issues which seem (for me) impossible to solve.
I tried to fix the memory allocation, but it didn't work (I don't understand that much of memory in C ;( )

Comment: I think char *left1 = copied[0][0][1]; etc. should be just char left1 = copied[0][0][1]; since char *left1 declares a pointer.

Comment: To me it looks more like it should be `char *left1 = &copied[0][0][1];`, and so on.

Comment: You don't need dynamic allocation (`malloc` and `free`) — each `rubik_t` object already contains all the memory it needs.

Comment: Also, I think the order of assignments in your rotation function is messed up. One way to ensure it's good is by using 12 temporary variables. First copy from the array to temporary variables, then from temporary variables back into the array. This will also eliminate the need for explicit pointers in your rotation function. Simpler code = fewer bugs!

Comment: see [Quaternion rotation does not work as excepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024016/2521214) for some inspiration. Its 3x3 rubic cube with solver but the stuff for rotation `void RubiCube::axises_obj` is written in uncommon way (much slower than just numericaly swap axises) so I can animate any partial rotation not just 90deg as a result it might be easily expanded to any size...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass a pointer to your 3d array. You can just pass the array itself:

```
//Copy the Input Cube into a new Array
int copyRubik(rubik_t rubik, rubik_t copied){
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            for(k = 0; k < 2; k++){
                copied[i][j][k] = rubik[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//Function to turn the Top of the Cube
void turnTop(rubik_t copied){
    char temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5;
    char *left1 = &copied[0][0][1];
    char *left2 = &copied[0][1][1];
    char *right1 = &copied[2][1][1];
    char *right2 = &copied[2][0][1];
    char *top1 = &copied[3][0][1];
    char *top2 = &copied[3][1][1];
    char *bottom1 = &copied[1][1][1];
    char *bottom2 = &copied[1][0][1];
    char *sideTopL = &copied[4][0][1];
    char *sideBotL = &copied[4][0][0];
    char *sideTopR = &copied[4][1][1];
    char *sideBotR = &copied[4][1][0];

    temp1 = *top1;
    temp2 = *top2;
    temp3 = *sideBotL;
    temp4 = *sideTopL;
    temp5 = *sideTopR;
    *left1 = *bottom1;
    *left2 = *bottom2;
    *sideBotL = *sideBotR;
    *right1 = temp1;
    *right2 = temp2;
    *sideTopL = temp3;
    *sideTopR = temp4;
    *sideBotR = temp5;
    *top1 = *left1;
    *top2 = *left2;
    *bottom1 = *right1;
    *bottom2 = *right2;
}


     copyRubik(cube_ordered, copiedCube);
     turnTop(copiedCube);
```

This works in C99 and above.